# Java decrypt PHP oppenssl_encrypt message. Alway get tag mismatch

Tags: java, authentication, encryption, tags, aes

I am trying to implement a decryption method for php openssl_encrypted text. I got the Base64 encoded iv, Base64 encoded tag and cyphertext. However, my code below always prompt `Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!` Any idea what I did wrong in the code below?

PHP code

```
<?php
//$key should have been previously generated in a cryptographically safe way, like openssl_random_pseudo_bytes

$key="jKtbuVSQlhfbxF0zVjZh1839DLTNSvS5";

$plaintext = "121";
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    echo "iv " . base64_encode($iv) . "\n";

    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    echo "ciphertext " . $ciphertext . "\n";
    echo "tag " . base64_encode($tag) . "\n";
    echo "final message: " .  base64_encode($iv) . ":" . base64_encode($tag) . ":" . $ciphertext . "\n";

    //store $cipher, $iv, and $tag for decryption later
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}
?>
```

Java code

```
    String ENCRYPT_ALGO = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("jKtbuVSQlhfbxF0zVjZh1839DLTNSvS5".substring(0,16).getBytes(), "AES");

    //"Base64 encoded iv:Base64 encoded tag:cipherText"

    String[] chunks = "Axb5mI6ULfBrYjRC:A2Uxa8sFa8j1gK2YNZ6UTw==:PmAR".split("\\:");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO);
    byte[] iv =   Base64.getDecoder().decode(chunks[0]);
    byte[] tag = Base64.getDecoder().decode(chunks[1]);
    byte[] cipherText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(chunks[2]);

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new GCMParameterSpec(tag.length * 8, iv));

    byte[] destination = new byte[cipherText.length + tag.length];
    System.arraycopy(cipherText, 0, destination, 0, cipherText.length);
    System.arraycopy(tag, 0, destination, cipherText.length, tag.length);

    byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(destination);
    System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " +  new String(plainText));
```

Comment: The line `byte[] cipherText = chunks[2].getBytes()` uses an inappropriate encoding. Check the encoding used in the encryption code and decode accordingly (or share the encryption code). You should also not post dummy values like `aKey`, but valid test data (key, plaintext and concatenation of IV, tag and ciphertext).

Comment: I added a piece of php code and replace the key which is used in both code. Basically, php is working fine to encrypt and decrypt with the provided iv, tag and cipherText. Java is returning Tag mismatch

Comment: The tag in the test data is wrong. It is returned by `openssl_encrypt()` and must of course first be retrieved after the call of `openssl_encrypt()`. Furthermore, algorithm specification (AES-128) and key size (32 bytes) are inconsistent. These issues lead to an incorrect tag and key in the Java code. In addition, the Java code lacks the Base64 decoding of the ciphertext. In the PHP code the concatenation of IV, tag and ciphertext is missing.

Comment: so I updated my code except the key and the problem still persist. The php code is working fine with such key. What I need is to have Java code be able to decode under same condition. Is that possible?

Comment: AES-128 with a 32 bytes key? There is no such thing. PHP shortens the key implicitly to 16 bytes by truncating the end. Therefore you should take the correct key _directly_, which probably would have prevented the problem in the Java code. The Java code does not truncate implicitly, that must be done explicitly. Besides, the Java code still uses a wrong tag, i.e. you will still get a tag mismatch.

Comment: Thank you, that key truncation is exactly what I was looking for. I am able to decrypt the code now.